# using the iis authentication element

Tags: windows, iis-7, authorization, windows-authentication

I am trying out IIS authentication. 
I stared by trying to deny access from all users to the Default Web Site.

```
appcmd set config  "Default Web Site"   /commit:apphost /section:system.webServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Deny',users='*']"
```

The command seems to be successful - `Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/security/authorization" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"`

However, and when browsing `http://localhost/` the Default Web Site displayed as usual. This was also the case after restring it on the IIS Manager.

What am I doing wrong \ what else should I check ?

Following is the security section in my applicationhost.config -

```
    <location path="Default Web Site">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Deny" users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please check whether anonymous authentication is enabled in the Authentication, If both anonymous and windows authentication is enabled in IIS, and if we don't have a deny entry or anonymous in the web config then the resources on the web server are accessed using anonymous authentication.

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting this in applicationhost.config (which applies to every website you have hosted in IIS on that server) and not the web.config for the specific application?

Comment: @samwu but this deny entry is for all users. Anonymous authentication, if I understand it correctly, allows me to authenticate as a user, by given a password (and not by logging in, like in Windows authentication). So shouldn't this deny block both?

Comment: @GabrielLuci because in some configurations the security settings are protected, which means they must be configured from the applicationhost. didn't want to worry about it, so i set it the applictionhost.

Comment: Is the web.config overriding the settings in your applicationhost.config?

Comment: no, the web.config was empty. the applicationhost has global configuration, as well configuration for each site (in a location object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I set the authorization in the global scope to give all users all authorization accesses. This apparently has precedence.